# Roots of an entropy-like function

Tags: it.information-theory

Let
$x_s = \sin(\theta+\frac{2\pi s}{3})$ and
$y_s = 1+\cos(\frac{2\pi s}{3})$, $s=0,1,2$.

Define $f(\theta) = \sum_{s=0}^2 x_s\ln y_s$.

Is there any method to derive roots of $f(\theta)$.
I have run a simulation on it, and found that $\theta=0$ is a solution.
But I am unable to see how to analytically obtain it.

Comment: This would be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By trigonometry, $$f(\theta)= \log (2)\left( \sin\theta+\cos(\pi/6-\theta)-\cos(\pi/6+\theta) \right)=\log(4)\sin\theta.$$

---

For the revised problem, we have this: $f(\theta)$ is $2\pi/3$-periodic, and $f(\theta)$ is odd, so it suffices to find the roots between $0$ and $\pi/3$ (both of which are themselves roots). Plotting indicates that $f(\theta)$ is unimodal on this interval, $f'(\theta)$ is strictly increasing, and $f''(\theta)$ is strictly increasing, and $f'''(\theta)\geq 6$. Each of these observations follows from the one after it (sometimes needing to also evaluate at $\theta=0$), and the last one seems easiest to prove. Not elegant, certainly, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't express my question correctly.
The $\theta$ is in $y_s$ too.
Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: In $y_s$ where?

Comment: It should be $y_s=1+\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi s}{3})$